# If sequence of derivatives converges uniformly is function sequence increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $g_n : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions where $g_n'(x)$ converges to $1+x^2$ uniformly does $g_n$ necessarily converge to an increasing function?

I claimed the answer was no, since we do not know about the convergence of $g_n$ at any point in $\mathbb{R}$ what would be the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g_n(x) = a_n+ x+ \frac{1}{3}x^3 $. You can choose $a_n$ to be any sequence of numbers.

Comment: So the answer is correct but for the wrong reason?

Comment: This is just a particular example. Your idea is correct, you just need to make it more precise.

Comment: This was just a true or false question. So would my answer qualify as correct?

Comment: Yes, $g_n$ does not necessarily converge